Windows 11 Bluetooth Pairing using Simple Secure Pairing (SSP) mode Numeric Comparison
I am having trouble with Bluetooth Pairing on Windows 11 using Simple Secure Pairing SSP mode Numeric Comparison.
I have created a BLE peripheral with Bluetooth v4.2 hardware, capable of handling (most) of SSP including Numeric Comparison.
Then using the Windows SDK, to requesting custom Pairing with the peripheral:
result = await deviceInformation.Pairing.Custom.PairAsync(DevicePairingKinds.ConfirmPinMatch, devicePairingProtectionLevel).AsTask(cancellationToken);

(Other DevicePairingProtectionLevel were attempted as well)
The application subscribes to the custom pairing callback:
deviceInformation.Pairing.Custom.PairingRequested += OnPairingRequested;

And is called back as expected indicating the negotiated mode is indeed ConfirmPinMatch and has a matching Pin argument.
Each device then accept the pairing request, but the original PairAsync method never returns on Windows 11 using Bluetooth v5.3 hardware. (thus Ive added the AsTask extension to allow cancellation).
Yet, this code works on Windows 10 using Bluetooth v4.1 hardware, when pairing to the very same BLE peripheral. And I have also confirmed the correct operation of this BLE peripheral when using an Android device to Pair with it. Android which handles all Pairing in the OS itself.
So this evidence suggests the problem is in Windows 11.
Its worth noting that both Windows 10 and 11 machines support a different version of bluetooth so its not a comparison without difference, but SSP was introduced in Bluetooth v2.1 so i wouldn't expect the SDK now to hang indefinitely due to the unequal versions used.
I have no idea how to debug this, or even report a bug.
It's not like the Windows OS or SDK is open source and i can step through what the API is doing... or is it?
Ive limited experience with windows programming so Im not sure where to take this issue.
(Fwiw Ive tried targeting different versions including the latest windows10.0.26100.0)
Please advise.

Try to disable Authentication Agent. That may block execution.

SSP is something in Bluetooth Classic and not BLE. You're probably mixnig up the terminology. Also, what version your Bluetooth hardware has is irrelevant because the pairing part of BLE runs within the host (Windows). You should try to file a bug report to Microsoft if you believe it's not working as expected.

@Emil Your similar comment was already answered about a year ago and it looks since that time you still did not read BT Spec. I copied that reply: Regarding to UG103.14: Bluetooth® LE Fundamentals: "Bluetooth low energy standard versions 4.0 and 4.1 use the Secure Simple Pairing model, in which users can choose one method from Just Works, Passkey Entry, and Out-of-Band mechanisms based on the input/output capability of the devices"

And still as I wrote in my answer, "That UG103.14 document seems to be written by some people at Silabs; it is not an official document written by Bluetooth SIG. That BLE would use Secure Simple Pairing is just wrong.". In the Bluetooth Core spec v6.0, Vol 1 Part A, section 5.4, there is even a comparison that compares LE security against SSP.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69944183/secure-simple-pairing-vs-le-legacy-pairing

@MikePetrichenko if youve done it before, could you point me to info on how to disable the Authentication Agent? I cant find the Policy in my machine that online search suggested

@axa Open Settings > Bluetooth & devices > Devices. Under Related settings, select More Bluetooth settings to find more Bluetooth options. Uncheck "Notify me when new device connected" (The second checkbox from the top)

@Emil it does seem a bit hard to follow, when SSP was introduced with 4.0 along with BLE, and then 4.2 makes improvements including LE Secure Pairing.
But regardless for this issue i was merely trying to implement the associated method Numeric Comparison, which in fact was available in that latter update.
Looking into these specs deeper I found reference to use of the Authentication requirements flags and setting those properly allowed Windows to respond to the request.  That said it just hanging without detail of its behavior does seem like a bug. But filing with Microsoft seem so daunting

@MikePetrichenko Thanks. Worth noting I didnt need to do this as i found the Authentication requirements flags which adjusting them allowed the call to return.

@Emit Just Works is a Numeric Companion that done internally by deriver or by firmware (depends on implementation).

So it appears that not having set the Authentication requirements flags correctly was the root cause of my issue.
I haven't diagnosed if it is a requirement of Windows or Bluetooth, but when the machine running win 11 and BT5.3 the call to bond failed to return with a peripheral that set neither the Secure Connections and/or MITM protection flag.
This on the surface seem to me like a bug in Windows if the call never returns, and I should've fallen back to whatever worked with win10 4.1.
Regardless if your here searching why this call isn't returning for you, you can check these settings on your peripheral.
